# How to run a conduit from wall over fireplace to cabinet

Tags: electrical, drywall, conduit

I'm trying to hide the TVs low voltage umbilical cord thing and would love to make it look nice and be ready for the future. Right now it just goes up and over the built-in but I want it hidden. Preferably I'd have a conduit going at a diagonal straight into the cabinet but I worry that might be almost impossible to do without tearing out the entire wall. I'm also thinking about doing a conduit to the built in (yellow) and then a hidden channel down to the cabinet that isn't in the wall but nestled up against the side of the builtin.

What do yall think? Would blue be impossible?

[image]

Comment: Depending on the fireplace construction details, you may not have much stud space to work with, as it may be bricks all the way up there.

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be to use some wiremold from the back of the TV, run down the wall to the mantel, then across the mantel to the built-in and through it.  Paint the wiremold to match the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any conduit installed behind the wall will be difficult without cutting holes because you have that window above the cabinet. You're going to probably have a king and jack stud supporting the window. You'd have to drill through both to get behind the cabinet.  You could just cut a small slot in the drywall down to the studs and install the  cable in it and them patch and paint.

Have you considered any of the small wire molds available like the ones shown below from amazon? Just a short piece from the cabinet to behind the TV.

[image]

Comment: If I removed the drywall where the studs are, do you think it would be too much of a pain to go through them, and to put a conduit in? Do you know the code implications on this? I'm going for a clean look on the wall around the TV. Do you think I could embed a channel in the drywall and make it flush (for your third suggestion).

Comment: Until you open the wall up, you won't know what's there.  You might have single studs for drywall support and have the window supported by the exterior wall.  Once the wall is open, the rest would be easy but you'd have a larger area to patch and paint.  You could embed a channel just the thickness of the cable and repairing the drywall would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding it won't make it futureproof. If at a later date, you want to connect video, free to air box, speakers, etc, that needs consideration. It looks like the existing wire goes *behind* the unit on the left. I'd take the wire straight up, behind the tv, then across horizontally to go behind the unit. Put into some sheathing, it will be a shorter piece on show. Heck, you could even put a matching one on the right of the tv!

A neater way may be to add to the fancy 'cornicing' on the mantlepiece, and just add a vertical sheath from the bottom of the tv down to it. Possibly 'cornicing' high enough to reach the tv?